# Add spring configuration files to classpath when coming from maven dependancy

Tags: spring, maven, classpath

I have:

```
Project
     \-src/main/resources
     \-src/main/java
     \-src/test/resources
                        \-TestDataSourceContext.xml
     \-src/test/java
```

and

```
DatabaseUtils
     \-src/main/resources
     \-src/main/java
     \-src/test/resources
                        \-AbstractTestDataSourceContext.xml
     \-src/test/java
```

In my Pom for Project I have a dependency as follows:
  `

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.co.domain.databaseutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>DatabaseUtils</artifactId>
        <version>${buildVersion}</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

Then in `TestDataSourceContext.xml` I have:

```
<import resource="classpath:AbstractTestDataSourceContext.xml"/>
```

Of course I get a `filenotfoundexception` when trying to do the import when running unit tests for `Project`, as `AbstractTestDataSourceContext.xml` is not included on the classpath.  Is there a straightforward way of getting this file on the class path?  Is there a maven option, a plugin etc?  So when I depend on `DatabaseUtils` I can take all it's resources, get `DatabaseUtils` to package it's resource etc... I am still relatively new to Maven but it seems bizarre to me that this would be complicated to do.

Comment: "I am still relatively new to Maven but it seems bizarre to me that this would be complicated to do"... better get used to it, "bizarre and complicated" is the Maven way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you usually do, you include another dependency with scope test:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>uk.co.domain.databaseutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>DatabaseUtils</artifactId>
    <version>${buildVersion}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>
```

It tells maven to include test-jar (should be called DatabaseUtils-<version>-tests.jar) on classpath for running tests (scope test).

This assumes there is a proper DatabaseUtils test jar available which should be the case if it's installed in a default way by maven.